# Javascript - Como passar parâmetros para uma função de um Event Attribute

Tags: javascript

Não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar um código, onde crio uma função separadamente e chamo-a toda vez que quiser, porém mudando apenas os parâmetros. O javascript não executa

```
function minhaFuncao(num1, num2) {
    //codigo
}

variavel.onclick = minhaFuncao(num1, num2);
```

Como eu faço isso funcionar? Ele apenas funciona se eu escrevo o nome da função, sem os parâmetros, tipo:

```
variavel.onclick = minhaFuncao;
```

Porém eu gostaria de passar parâmetros para a função depois do "onclick".

OBS: Sem declarar a função logo após o onclick, quero que ela seja declarada anteriormente, só mude os parâmetros.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você utiliza `minhaFuncao(num1, num2);`, o *JavaScript* interpreta que você está chamando a função e que deseja que ela seja executada, por isso não funciona dessa forma.

No seu caso, você precisa criar uma função anônima e dentro dessa função chamar uma outra (passando os parâmetros, claro).

**Exemplo:**

```
function minhaFuncao(num1, num2) {
    alert( num1 + num2 )
}

variavel.onclick = function() {
    minhaFuncao(10, 20);
}
```

Comment: Isso vale para `elemento.addEventListener` também.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi como você deseja utilizar a função, mas esse é o comportamento esperado. Pense que o onClick funciona como um evento que pode ser disparado em vários momentos no código, mas você tem que passar os parâmetros quando chamar o evento. Por exemplo:

```js
var Evento = {
  onClick: null
}

function soma(n1, n2){
  var sum = n1+n2;
  console.log("Soma: "+sum);
}

//Configura ação do evento - handler
Evento.onClick = soma;

//Usuário faz alguma ação e vc dispara o onClick
Evento.onClick(1,1);

//Usuário faz outra ação e vc dispara outro onClick
Evento.onClick(2,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
function minhaFuncao(num1, num2) {
  alert(num1 + num2);
}
button.onclick = minhaFuncao.bind(null, 2, 2);
```

```html
<button>CLIQUE</button>
```

#### Referência

- [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)